# Clojure app built with lein uberjar not launching

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have a small command-line Clojure app that is built with 'lein uberjar'. The result jar file, when started does not call my main function, nor does it give me any kind of stack trace or other indication of an error condition.

```
% lein version
Leiningen 2.0.0 on Java 1.7.0_10 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
% lein uberjar
Compiling spelunker.core
Compiling spelunker.core
Created /Users/temerson/Work/ddp-qa-tool/spelunker/target/spelunker-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Including spelunker-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Including lucene-core-3.6.2.jar
Including clojure-1.4.0.jar
Created /Users/temerson/Work/ddp-qa-tool/spelunker/target/spelunker-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar 

% java -jar target/spelunker-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
%
```

It should display a usage message, instead nothing. I've checked the (to me) obvious things: my project file contains

```
(defproject spelunker "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Spelunk through Lucene data to find nuggets of useful data."
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.apache.lucene/lucene-core "3.6.2"]]
  :main spelunker.core
  :aot [spelunker.core])
```

and spelunker/core.clj includes

```
(ns spelunker.core
  (:import (org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard StandardAnalyzer)
           (org.apache.lucene.document Document Field Field$Store Field$Index)
           (org.apache.lucene.index IndexReader IndexWriter IndexWriter$MaxFieldLength)
           (org.apache.lucene.store NIOFSDirectory RAMDirectory)
           (org.apache.lucene.util Version))
  (:gen-class))
```

and the main function is defined thusly (for now):

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (print "DAFUQ?"))
```

For all intents and purposes this should work: if I create a stub app with `leiningen app new` it works fine. But not with the above.

I'd feel fine if I at least got some kind of stack trace (i.e., something I could investigate), but the silence is killing me.

Anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: To be able to run via `java -jar` you need a manifest with a MainClass attribute. AFAIK uberjar doesn't do this automatically.

Comment: I thought that was the entire point of uberjar. And if that were the case then I would expect the stubbed `leiningen app new` wouldn't work, but it does: I can build an uberjar with that and invoke the result with `java -jar`. Looking at the jar it builds for my app, there is a manifest and it does include a `Main-Class: spelunker.core` line, so that isn't it. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Yeah, turns out you don't have to explicitly set the Main-Class manifest attribute like you do others. In that case I'm not sure what might be going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not flush before exit. Change `print` to `println` in `-main` and the newline will auto flush, or otherwise follow your print with an explicit flush.

Comment: Wow... that did it. I feel like an idiot. I actually had a `"\n"` in the string on my machine and figured that would cause the flush, but it doesn't. Changing to `println` forced the flush. Thank you!